# flutter plugins not recognized in android studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I have updated the android studio to android 4.0 but after updating my flutter plugins are not recognized by it. however it was working fine with android 3.X

Whats the solution of it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try closing and opening it again? also, i would recommend switching the theme to dark mode ;)

Comment: I have restarted the android studio, but it didn't work

Comment: Try to uninstall and reinstall the plugins.

Comment: @hisam I have tried to uninstalling and reinstalling the plugins, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem with Android Studio 4.0.1, despite of having all the plug-ins (Flutter and Dart), restarting the IDE many times, AS isn't able to reflect ant Flutter plugin.  Any suggestions/solutions please?

Comment: I am trying to install flutter in android studio 4.0. But I fail to see any option to run/build flutter application.